# Combining rows of certain values with aggregate, and then returning aggregate subset to data frame

Tags: r

Newbie here again, determined to produce a better reproducible question than I did last time. My data frame:

```
> str(Denton)
'data.frame':   1666 obs. of  8 variables:
$ MIL.ID     : Factor w/ 18840 levels "","0000151472",..: 7393 3955 3955 3955 3871 3871 8627 8627 1609 11652 ...
$ Center     : int  8130 8130 8130 8130 8130 8130 8130 8130 8130 8130 ...
$ Gift.Date  : Factor w/ 339 levels "","01/01/2015",..: 3 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 ...
$ Gift.Amount: num  25 50 50 50 25 25 50 50 2500 20 ...
$ Solic.     : Factor w/ 31 levels "","aa","ac","an",..: 24 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 11 11 ...
$ Tender     : Factor w/ 10 levels "","c","ca","cc",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
$ Account    : Factor w/ 16 levels "","29101-0000",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Restriction: Factor w/ 258 levels "","AAU","ACA",..: 1 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 ...

> head(Denton)
MIL.ID     Center   Gift.Date         Gift.Amount Solic. Tender    Account Restriction
0000741377   8130 01/02/2015           25          ps     ca       29101-0000            
0000551071   8130 01/05/2015           50          mem    ca       29101-0000 BWC
0000551071   8130 01/05/2015           50          mem    ca       29101-0000 BWC
0000551071   8130 01/05/2015           50          mem    ca       29101-0000 BWC
0000544358   8130 01/06/2015           25          mem    ca       29101-0000 BWC
0000544358   8130 01/06/2015           25          mem    ca       29101-0000 BWC
```

My ultimate goal is simply to return summary data for this data frame, but with one caveat: there is one tender type, "pd", that is payroll deduction, and occurs 26 times a year. Each payroll deduction is technically part of one gift, i.e. not 26 gifts, but one. What I am attempting to do is combine gift amounts associated with pd AND MIL.ID (which is a donor ID), so each person's multiple payroll deductions are combined into one gift. This part was not too hard, given some help I found in some other examples here on stack overflow:

```
> df <- aggregate(Gift.Amount~MIL.ID,subset(Denton,Tender=="pd"),sum)
> head(df)
   MIL.ID     Gift.Amount
1 0000308080         324
2 0000308492          24
3 0000756682           4
4 0000757228          24
5 0000776957         850
6 0000777108         213
```

This data frame contains those MIL.IDs associated with the payroll deductions, and summed those pd entries under each MIL.ID. Now comes the part where my puny brain caves in on itself. Recall earlier that I wanted to simply

```
summary(Denton)
```

to snatch out means and medians once I had summed pd's under Tender with their associated MIL.ID. Problematically, the aggregated data for payroll deductions solely exists as an independent data frame now. I somehow need to:

1) eliminate the old pd rows under Tender, 
2) combine the Denton and DF data frames
3) Summarize the data

Here is what I have been able to figure out in base R:

```
>Denton[Denton$Tender!=pd,]
```

Now those original pd's under tender are gone. However, I cannot cbind Denton and df back together, as:

```
>str(df)
data.frame':    77 obs. of  2 variables:
$ MIL.ID     : Factor w/ 18840 levels "","0000151472",..: 1613 1617 7967 7991 8627 8637 8797 8899 9807 11371 ...
$ Gift.Amount: num  324 24 4 24 850 213 360 4 11 24 ...
```

Both data frames are rectangular and of different length, so R cannot work a cbind out without kicking out a

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 502, 77.
```

Is there a way in base R to tackle this issue, or do I need to download the reshape package and learn how to melt? Do I even need to complicate things this much by using the aggregate function?

EDIT for comments:

Current head() for Denton:

```
 > head(Denton)
MIL.ID     Center   Gift.Date         Gift.Amount Solic. Tender    Account Restriction
0000741377   8130 01/02/2015           25          ps     ca       29101-0000            
0000551071   8130 01/05/2015           50          mem    pd       29101-0000 BWC
0000551071   8130 01/05/2015           50          mem    pd       29101-0000 BWC
0000551071   8130 01/05/2015           50          mem    pd       29101-0000 BWC
0000544358   8130 01/06/2015           25          mem    pd       29101-0000 BWC
0000544358   8130 01/06/2015           25          mem    pd       29101-0000 BWC
```

Desired output once the things I want to accomplish are done:

```
> head(Denton)
MIL.ID     Center   Gift.Date         Gift.Amount Solic. Tender    Account Restriction
0000741377   8130 01/02/2015           25          ps     ca       29101-0000            
0000551071   8130 01/05/2015          150          mem    pd       29101-0000 BWC
0000544358   8130 01/06/2015           50          mem    pd       29101-0000 BWC
0000556000   8130 01/05/2015           50          mem    ca       29101-0000 BWC
0000556005   8130 01/05/2015           50          mem    ca       29101-0000 BWC
0000556100   8130 01/05/2015           50          mem    ca       29101-0000 BWC
```

Then I would just

```
>summary(Denton)
```

to get my means and medians now that the pd's under tender have been merged for each MIL.ID.

How about this for the Dplyr function:

```
> Denton %>%
     group_by(MIL.ID) %>% #sorts by MIL.ID
     select(MIL.ID, Gift.Amount, Tender) %>% #selects these three for agg
     filter(sum(Tender) <= pd) %>% #I think this should sum where tender= pd?
     distinct #get distinct rows?
```

Comment: Are you looking for means and medians by MIL.ID or for the entire df?

Comment: Can you update your question to show an example of the final data frame you're trying to generate?

Comment: Certainly. I will inject a couple rows with the pd type under tender to make it meaningful.

Comment: just so i understand this correctly, for a given pd, all values are going to be

Comment: For a given MIL.ID, all pd values under Tender will be combined such that the associated Gift.Amount numerical values are added and multiple pd entries become one pd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses the [`dplyr` package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html). It's not base R but simplifies things tremendously so well worth adding to your a*R*senal of tools. *(sorry, couldn't help myself...)*

```
library(dplyr)
Denton <- data.frame("MIL.ID" = c(1,2,2,3,3,4),
                    "Tender" = c("ca", "pd", "pd", "pd", "pd", "ab"),
                    "Gift.Amount" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                    "Solic" = c("ps", "mem", "mem", "mem", "mem", "ps")
                    )
```

This gives

```
  MIL.ID Tender Gift.Amount Solic
1      1     ca           1    ps
2      2     pd           2   mem
3      2     pd           3   mem
4      3     pd           4   mem
5      3     pd           5   mem
6      4     ab           6    ps
```

Now, use dplyr's functions to do what you want:

```
Denton %>% group_by(MIL.ID) %>%  # This groups by MIL.ID    
        mutate( Gift.Amount = sum(Gift.Amount)) %>%   # This gets the sum of each Gift.Amount
        distinct # This gets the distinct rows
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: MIL.ID [4]

  MIL.ID Tender Gift.Amount  Solic
   (dbl) (fctr)       (dbl) (fctr)
1      1     ca           1     ps
2      2     pd           5    mem
3      3     pd           9    mem
4      4     ab           6     ps
```

---

**Notes**:

This assumes that for a given `MIL.ID`, all `pd` rows are similar except for the Gift.Amount, which seems like the case based on your example above. (If it isn't, then update your question with what logic to use to decide which row to keep and I'll update my answer to use that logic.)

I also took the `sum` over all `Tenders`, instead of just the `pd` tender since the sum of one item is just that item's value and doing it that way means I don't need to separate then bind back two different dfs.

---

**Edit**

The other option is you can separate your `Denton` df into two:

```
df_notpd <- Denton %>% filter(Tender != "pd");
df_pd <- Denton %>% filter(Tender == "pd");


# Now do the necessary logic on *only* the pd portion.
df_pd <- df_pd group_by(MIL.ID) %>%  # This groups by MIL.ID    
        mutate( Gift.Amount = sum(Gift.Amount)) %>%   # This gets the sum of each Gift.Amount
        distinct # This gets the distinct rows

# Then rbind back with df_notpd
df <- rbind(df_notpd, df_pd)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works. As to your aRsenal pun up top: http://orig01.deviantart.net/fbc0/f/2012/129/d/b/scorpion_strangulation_fatality_mk_by_aeruhl-d4z67tk.gif

Comment: I am sorry to uncheck, but I ran into an issue. When we summed Tender types, the assumption was that the only type with multiple entries was pd. This, however, is not the case. There are some entries where a donor gave twice in one year, (say, twice on a telephone drive) but those are technically considered separate donations. I will look at the dplyr package more in depth, but is there a way to modify your code such that only pd is summed for each MIL.ID?

Comment: The reason not summing non-pd related gifts is important: it messes with my measures of central tendency. Average gift size (donation) is a big deal in philanthropic orgs, and I want to make sure it is as accurate as possible.

Comment: Check original question for my attempt with dplyr

Comment: Doesn't work. Sum is not meaningful for factors, as it is literally attempting to sum pd, and not the associated gift amount.

Comment: I used it and it worked with one caveat: I had to change the first line of code on the logic portion to: df_pd <- group_by(df_pd, MIL.ID) %>% to get it to function appropriately. Thank you again, buddy.

Comment: ah, yes. That should've been `df_pd %>% group_by(MIL.ID) %>%....`. Glad to see you figured it out :)